# how to convert Xmlstring to Xmlfile or QDomDocument

Tags: qt

If I have a string which contains proper xml format and I want to convert it to an XML file so I can use Xpath to parse it properly.

How do I do this? please give me some valid example  and i also want to load those each xml node value into Qtablewidgetitem how can i do..please help mee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a string which contains proper
>   xml format and I want to convert it to
>   an XML file

This requires a normal file writing which saved under the extension `.xml`. Check out the example given for file writing in the [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qfile.html#details) for Qt 4.6.

> i also want to load those each xml
>   node value

For this you require `QDomDocument`, `QDomElement` etc., to retrieve the values and the nodes stored in the XML file.

Check out the examples given for [QDomDocument](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qdomdocument.html#details) documentation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several [`QDomDocument::setContent`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qdomdocument.html#setContent) calls you can use to load data to a QDomDocument. The same document also lists an example: http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/itemviews-simpledommodel.html